# Prevent esc from stopping audio playback

Tags: html, wmp

So, I've got a web application running only on IE11. I use a windows media player control to play an audio file.

If the user presses escape on the page, the playing of the audio file is ended.

How can I prevent this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
      <OBJECT CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" type="application/x-oleobject">
        <PARAM name="URL" value="http://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/%20MAY%202014%20LATEST%20ADDITIONS/PUBLIC%20DOMAIN%20MUSIC/626%5Bkb%5Dbuster-brown-gonna-make-you-happy-1943.mp3.mp3">
      </OBJECT>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Why can't you use the `<audio>` element?

Comment: Dai, because my sources are wav files encoded with the GSM codec. the <audio> element does not support those... (sucks, I know!)

Answer (score 0):

Try using javascript. (If you using only IE it should be work)

```
document.attachEvent("onkeydown", keyHandler);

function keyHandler() {
if(event.keyCode == 27)
    {
        event.returnValue = false;
        event.keyCode = 0;
        break;
    }
}
```

27 is ESC key value.

And, this is alternative way.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
    var charCode = e.charCode || e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (charCode == 27){
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Alas this won't work... already tried that.
It seems the WMP object is listening to the keyboard outside of the DOM event model...?

Comment: @palloquin Oh,it is out of my knowledge so I will try find another solution later. Thank you for response.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this to disable it

```
(document).keyup(function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 27) { // escape key maps to keycode `27`
         e.preventDefault();
         return false;
    }
});
```